# Unique index not so unique

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm trying to purposely create and attempt to write a duplicate on a unique index on MongoDB for testing purposes.  My code is essentially:

```
db.collection("foo").ensureIndex({a: 1}, {unique: true}, function () {
    db.collection("foo").insert({a: "foo"}, function () {
        db.collection("foo").insert({a: "foo"});
    });
});
```

However, this doesn't fail in any way.  If I connect to my DB and run `db.foo.find({a: "foo"})` I will find *two* results after this is run.  This indicates that the `{unique: true}` is not working properly/not doing anything/etc.

Using `createIndex` does not work either.

Am I using MongoDB unique indices incorrectly?

Comment: You should be checking the `err` (i.e. first) parameter to your callbacks to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this running the exact same code (wrapped with connect).  It errors as expected, leaving 1 doc in the db as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating the index correctly, but not correctly responding to potential errors being sent from the DB.

As you're using NodeJS, you need to check the first parameter of callbacks to check for errors (most NodeJS APIs with callbacks follow this pattern, as does the MongoDB NodeJS Native driver):

```
db.collection("foo").ensureIndex({a: 1}, {unique: true}, function (err) {
    if(err) { console.log('failed to create index: ', err); return; }
    db.collection("foo").insert({a: "foo"}, function (err) {
          if(err) { console.log('first insert failed: ', err); return; }
          db.collection("foo").insert({a: "foo"}, function (err) {
              if(err) { 
                   console.log('insert failed:', err); 
                   return;  
              }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That's fine, but the main problem is the fact that even though the error is engendered, the duplicate entry is still inserted

Comment: Are any of the errors shown? I just ran the code as is, and the only error was: `MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: test123.foo.$a_1  dup key: { : "foo" }`  You could try adding `background: false` to the options.

Comment: And, if there are already duplicates, you need to either clear the collection or add: `{dropDups: true}` to forcibly fix the data (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-creation/). An index won't be created if there are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

after i tryed in my mongo, i'm afraid the code is useful. and the record will be unique after ensure-index. you may check you mongo version or set err in callback to find any syntax err.